# Subtracting 1 column of a DateTimeIndex from another throws ValueErrors and TypeErrors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pivot-table

I have a pivot_table from pandas that has 70 columns and 25 rows, and I subset it with

```
dosage = test_df[test_df > 0][[7,8]].dropna()
```

which produces the table

```
date    2014-02-19 14:15:05 2014-03-25 13:15:26
barcode     
V0HX8          0.5                   0.4
V0NLH          0.4                   0.3
```

I am trying to create a column "difference that would look like:

```
date    2014-02-19 14:15:05 2014-03-25 13:15:26 Diff
barcode     
V0HX8          0.5                   0.4        -0.1
V0NLH          0.4                   0.3        -0.1
```

using the following code:

```
dosage["Diff"] = dosage["2014-03-25 13:15:26"] - dosage["2014-02-19 14:15:05"]
```

but get the error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I have also tried using the code:

```
dosage["Diff"] = dosage[[1]] - dosage[[0]] but get the error: KeyError: 'Diff'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `.iloc` for index location:

```
dosage['Diff'] = dosage.iloc[:,0] - dosage.iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the help